# Twitter bootstrap accordion in accordion won't collapse

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I am using twitter bootstrap to create a accordion in which each row item contains yet another accordion. The code below creates the accordion inside the accordion, but the inner accordion won't collapse, and I just can't figure out why.

```
$daysToBeShown: array(2) { [2]=> string(6) "Wednesday" [6]=> string(7) "Sunday" }

$teamForDaysArray: array(2) { ["Wednesday"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(18) "09:00-09:30 (1022)" [1]=> string(18) "09:30-10:00 (1023)" } ["Sunday"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(18) "16:10-16:50 (2033)" } }

<div class="accordion" id="accordion1">
<?php
foreach($daysToBeShown as $key => $value)
{
?>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapse<?php echo $key;?>">
        <?php echo $value;?>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse<?php echo $key;?>" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
<?php
foreach($teamForDaysArray[$value] as $keys => $valueInner)
{
?>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse<?php echo $valueInner;?>">
        <?php echo $valueInner;?>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse<?php echo $valueInner;?>" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px;">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php
}
?>
</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Niels Sønderbæk ... have you tried isolating this into a pure markup and JS fiddle to make sure it's nothing specific on your page that is causing this?

Comment: I wanted to check if it was doable in an isolated environment. http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/8VTt2/ So it's doable, and I don't see any errors on your code. Some other CSS or JS could be messing with it in your particular environment. Make sure all your id's are unique and that they are printing as you would expect them to with your PHP. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

So after some additional testing, I believe I've figured out the problem. The original id's contained spaces and brackets. Once I chose an id without spaces and brackets, it worked just fine. I'm not entirely sure if it was the spaces,brackets or both, which made the accoridion misbehave, but I would suggest to avoid using those with bootstrap accordion.